# Powerpoint how to get the current zoom % the user is at?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

Using Microsoft Interop assemblies I want to get the zoom percentage the user is currently at. By zoom percentage meaning the value of the bar in the bottom right in editing mode.

I know how to make the powerpoint object and open the file etc, just not sure how to get the zoom value.

Couldn't find anything online, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom
```

Should return number, so diplay it as `Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom + "%"` if needed.

Comment: That's done it. Thank you! I was using `SlideShowWindow` instead of `ActiveWindow` :). Will accept your answer when it lets me.